# r - Populate matrix with count data

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

Assume I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(teams=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
            players=c(5,2,1,2), 
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df
  teams players
1     A       5
2     B       2
3     C       1
4     D       2
```

I want to fill a weighted 4x4 matrix that resembles the pairwise combinations of one player on a team to all other players on all other teams.

With this example, the output should look like this:

```
m <- matrix(c(4,2,1,2,5,1,1,2,5,2,0,2,5,2,1,1), nrow=4, ncol=4)
colnames(m) <- df$teams
rownames(m) <- df$teams

> m
  A B C D
A 4 5 5 5
B 2 1 2 2
C 1 1 0 1
D 2 2 2 1
```

Note that a player from team A can play with:

- 4 other players from team A
- 2 players from team B
- 1 player from team C
- 2 players from team D

Does anyone know how to do this?

The real data holds thousands of teams and millions of players.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
size <- nrow(df)
diag(-1, size, size) + df$players

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    4    5    5    5
#[2,]    2    1    2    2
#[3,]    1    1    0    1
#[4,]    2    2    2    1
```

---

To set up the dimension names:

```
with(df, {
    size <- length(teams)
    m <- diag(-1, size, size) + players
    dimnames(m) <- list(teams, teams)
    m
})

#  A B C D
#A 4 5 5 5
#B 2 1 2 2
#C 1 1 0 1
#D 2 2 2 1
```